# Java - Rotating points on a circle

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, trigonometry

Have been playing around with some basic 3D. I'm trying to keep the math relatively simple as I'm only in year 9.

Background info:
I have 3 `int[]` variables called `xpoints`, `ypoints` and `zpoints`. I was thinking about putting them all in one List called `nodes` but decided it's easier not to.

The first forumla I tried was:

```
xpoints[i] = (int) (r*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(d)));
ypoints[i] = (int) (r*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(d)));
```

This worked perfectly for rotating the cube around one axis but not any others. I found a formula that looked promising for multiple axis but can't get it to work. The faces seem to shrink slightly during each loop, ending up in a single point (the centre).

```
xpoints[i] = (int) (x * cos_t - y * sin_t)
ypoints[i] = (int) (y * cos_t + x * sin_t)
```

The full function applying the math:

```
public void rotateZ(double theta){
    theta = Math.toRadians(theta);
    double cos_t = Math.cos(theta);
    double sin_t = Math.sin(theta);
    for (int i = 0; i < xpoints.length; i++){
        double x = xpoints[i] - x_off;
        double y = ypoints[i] - y_off - ypoints_mod[i];
        xpoints[i] = (int) (x * cos_t - y * sin_t) + x_off;
        ypoints[i] = (int) (y * cos_t + x * sin_t) + y_off + ypoints_mod[i];
        System.out.println(x+", "+y);
    }   
}
```

If you need anymore info please let me know (wasn't quite sure how to word this)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

amazing work for a 9 years old boy!! Great!!
search for [euler rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) for rotating a point or vector on all 3-axis.

Comment: Haha thanks, looked up euler rotation. Interested but it looks really confusing. Know any places that simplify it a bit? (Or is it really just that hard :) ) *Vote up for euler rotation, looks really handy

Answer (score 1):

Well... Don't you just love computer programming :). As shown in the code I was rounding the result to an `Integer` for convenience. Turns out this breaks it completely, removed that and it works fine.

DON'T ROUND WHEN DOING MATH ON COMPUTERS!!! :P

Never again